# How to override final_price.phtml in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, price, overrides

I want to override final_price.phtml, I have tried following in my module but it is not working. 
I have created **app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item> -->
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">MyVendor_MyModule::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

Also I have created template file as well. at **app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**
And in final_price.phtml I wrote my custom code.

But it is not working. 
Can anyone tell me what is missing in this code?

Comment: Have u flush magento cache after that?

Comment: Yes I checked Cache is disabled.

Comment: Did you ever found how to do that via layouts ? Because the plug-in solution is a bit awfull...

Comment: @pol No I don't know if its possible with layout or not.

Comment: check error log and comment it here

Comment: as i mentioned in my below answer keep files in view/base folder

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use alternative way for overriding template. Use below code. It will work.

**app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        <plugin name="MyVendor_MyModule_change_template" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\FinalPricePlugin" />
</type>
```

**MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\FinalPricePlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin;

class FinalPricePlugin
{
    public function beforeSetTemplate(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $subject, $template)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $enable=$objectManager->create('MyVendor\MyModule\Helper\Data')->chkIsModuleEnable();
        if ($enable) {
            if ($template == 'Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml') {
                return ['MyVendor_MyModule::product/price/final_price.phtml'];
            } 
            else
            {
                return [$template];
            }
        } else {
            return[$template];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Happy to hear that it helps you.

Comment: very helpful @kishan Patadia

Comment: A-W-E-S-O-M-E-!

Comment: using plugin is not good solution, because if you have multiple theme then it always take one template mentioned in  plugin , so from layout xml set your custom template which is mentioned in my below post

Comment: please post full content of file di.xml. Your code is only part of it and it's not working

Comment: what should be the full path of `final_price.phtml` inside the module?

Comment: It is app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

Comment: Working......!!!!

Answer (score 4):

No need to write plugin for this,  we have to do it in xml level

create a layout xml

**app\code\MYNAME_SPACE\MY_MODULE\view\base\layout\catalog_product_prices.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">MYNAME_SPACE_MY_MODULE::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

Above xml will effect only for simple product if you need to modify the bundle product then

```
<argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
```

should be

```
<argument name="bundle" xsi:type="array">
```

or in case of a configurable product

```
<argument name="configurable" xsi:type="array">
```

create a phtml that is

**\app\code\MYNAME_SPACE\MY_MODULE\view\base\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml**

Copy final_price from core module and modify it as you needed

to modify other price type you can refer

**vendor\magento\module-bundle\view\base\layout\catalog_product_prices.xml**

Comment: This did not work for me.  Using Magento 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to override `final_price.phtml` by re-creating the directory under my theme.

> Original file lives

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

> New file lives here

```
/app/design/frontend/NAMESPACE/MYTHEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

Comment: thats's not work in Magento 2.3

Answer (score 1):

1. Create app/code/Vendor/Module/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
        <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="configurable" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Cloudinfo_ChangesTheme::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </layout>
```

2. Add in module.xml:

```
       <sequence>
           <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
       </sequence>
```

3. Create app/code/Vendor/Moduleview/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
4. bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy && bin/magento c:c && bin/magento c:f

Comment: is this concept will work on M2.3.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

First check your **final_price.phtml** for any errors.

Now flush and clean the cache using cli commands

> bin/magento cache:clean
>
> bin/magento cache:flush

Now refresh.

Comment: No final_price.phtml don't have any error I have checked. and cache is disabled then also I tried above command but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that I could not overwrite `final_price.phml`. I solved the problem by adding `sequence` to the `module.xml` with Magento_Catalog (and then `setup:upgrade`):

```
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
    </sequence>
```