# How to recreate a core magento file in my own theme?

Tags: magento-2.1, module

Due to a bug in CE 2.1+ ([See Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4945), I am trying to replace a core Magento file:

\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox.php

with my own version.  However, I have tried inserting this into several different existing theme locations and it doesn't get picked up.

How can I replace this core file with my own version (You can see what I did in the above linked github thread).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override final price template as per following thread.

[How to override final_price.phtml in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166041/how-to-override-final-price-phtml-in-magento-2/166055#166055)

Comment: I think he wants to override the block

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, your solution is to replace the final_price.phtml file, which in my testing, didn't solve my problem (I'm trying to remove the As Low As completely), so far the only solution that I've found is to comment out he function renderAmountMinimal() contents in the FinalPriceBox.php file. So I'm trying to replace this actual file with my own version.

Comment: So far I haven't found an effective and functional solution to this problem. Odd.